# JavaScript. Как выровнять вывод значения числа по определённому формату?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, вёрстка, строки

Есть код, который выводит различные числа в браузере `some text ${some_num} some text`. Необходимо отображать это число в формате `XX.XXX`. Например `12.142` , `98.234` или `00.000`. т.е. необходимо отображать 2 знака с лева и 3 знака с права. Как это сделать в JS?

Comment: А если число от 100 и больше?

Comment: @zhurof оно гарантированно > 100.

Comment: он про `AA` говорит из твоего формата `AA.BBB`

Comment: @Vadim я понимаю. Если число > 100 по модулю, то АА часть тоже будет > 100 =)

Comment: Отрицательные числа возможны? Если да, что делать с минусом? при целом числе с одной цифрой он должен занимать место нуля или прибавляться к нулю? Если цифры две, тогда минус ведь будет всё равно сдвигать число вправо.

Comment: @Rivand `> 100` означает "Больше 100" ) Вы имели в виду `< 100`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, вы правы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat(options={minimumIntegerDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits: 3, minimumFractionDigits:3}).format(some_number)
```

Но поточнее бы что делать в случаях > 100, < 10 и тп

Comment: Ваше решение оказалось самым удобным. Единственно что нужно писать без `options=` и в `NumberFormat` первым аргументом передать локаль, иначе не работает. Т.е. будет `new Intl.NumberFormat('En-en',{minimumIntegerDigits:2, maximumFractionDigits: 3, minimumFractionDigits:3}).format(some_number)`

Answer (score 4):

```js
function formatNumber(num){
  num = +num;
  if(!isFinite(num)) return false;
  var result = num.toFixed(3);
  if(num >=0 && num < 10)  result = '0' + result;
  if(num < 0 && num > -10)  result = result.replace('-','-0');
  return result;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="console.log(formatNumber(this.value))">
```

Comment: А в стандартной библиотеке JS не чего для этого нет? Задача вроде как тривиальная, не хотелось бы заниматься велосипедостроением. Даже в С++ это делается по наитию.

Comment: Ждите ещё ответов, может и есть способы проще

Comment: Почему .toFixed(2) когда автор просит 3 знака после точки?

Comment: `NaN == NaN` дает `false`

Comment: @NoSkill , позор на мои седины ) поправил

Comment: @AzizUmarov , действительно

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант с использованием последних фишек JS )

```js
function format(value) {
  value = !!value ? '' + value : '0.0'; // проверяем валидность вхождения и переводим в строку
  const parts = value.split('.'); // разбиваем по точке

  return parts[0].padStart(2, '0') + '.' + (parts[1] ?? '0').padEnd(3, '0'); //возвращаем отформатированную строку и если вдруг дали нам целое число - подставляем в правую часть '0'
}


console.log(format());
console.log(format(1));
console.log(format(20));
console.log(format(300));
console.log(format(25.25));
console.log(format(250.250));
```